# How to import term in TaxonomyHiddenList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem, taxonomy, term-store

As i'm in sharepoint 2010 and in sandbox solution, i can't use taxonomy field.
I've created a new term store and i'd like import them in in the list TaxonomyHiddenList

Like this, i'll be abble to do a camlquery, retrieve the item with id and if i set my item with this, it'll work

```
item["taxonomy"] = itTaxonomy.id+";#"+itTaxonomy["Term"]
```

thans for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a powershell script.
it works but MS are not agree to modify this list

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url=Read-Host "Site Url"
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite $url
$web = Get-SPWeb($url)
$termSet = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $url
$termStore = $termSet.TermStores["Remote UnPartitionned Metadata Service Application"]
#récupère le term set du groupe Categories
$termGroup = $termStore.Groups["Taxonomie MLOZ"]

$termStoreId = $termGroup.Id

$listTaxo = $web.Lists["TaxonomyHiddenList"]


foreach ($termGroups in $termGroup.TermSets)
{
    $termSetId = $termGroups.Id
    foreach ($term in $termGroups.GetAllTerms()) 
    {
        #getNode $termSets
        $i = 0
        $parent = ""
        $termParent = $term.Parent
        while($i -le 6)
        {

            if($termParent.Id -ne $null)
            {
                $parent += $termParent.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")+":"
            }
            else
            {
                break
            }
            $termParent = $termParent.Parent
            $i++
        }
        $test = $parent.split(",")
        [array]::Reverse($test)
        $parent = $test -join ','

        $parent += $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")

        $newItem = $listTaxo.Items.Add()
        $newItem["Title"] = $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")
        $newItem["IdForTermStore"] = $termStoreId
        $newItem["IdForTerm"] = $term.id
        $newItem["IdForTermSet"] = $termSetId
        $newItem["Term"] = $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")
        $newItem["Path"] = $parent
        $newItem["Term1033"] = $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")
        $newItem["Path1033"] = $parent

        #Update the object so it gets saved to the list
        $newItem.Update()


    }
}
```